# I want to access count varibale at badgecontent in styledbadge for add to cart icon in return method i am counting number of records in json file , i

Tags: reactjs

```js
const NavBar = () => {

    async function getAllUsers() {
        const response = await getUsers();
        var items = response.data.length;
        var count = items;
        console.log(count);
    }
    `enter code here`

    return (

        <AppBar className={classes.header} position="static">
            <Toolbar>
                <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="./" exact>Macine Test</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="all" exact>All Products</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="add" exact>Add Products</NavLink>
                <NavLink className={classes.right} to="cart"><StyledBadge badgeContent={`enter code here`} color="secondary"><ShoppingCartIcon></ShoppingCartIcon></StyledBadge></NavLink>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );

};

export default NavBar;
```

The `count` variable is returning the number of records but I want to access it in `badgeContent` of `StyledBadge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const NavBar = () => {

    async function getAllUsers() {
        const response = await getUsers();
        var items = response.data.length;
        var count = items;
        console.log(count);
    }

    const [[count, error], setCount] = useState([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        getAllUsers().then(c => setCount([c]), e => setCount([, e]));
    }, []);

    if (error) {
        // TODO: Show an error (or a default value) when `error` is set
    }

    return <AppBar className={classes.header} position="static">
        <Toolbar>
            <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="./" exact>Macine Test</NavLink>
            <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="all" exact>All Products</NavLink>
            <NavLink className={classes.tabs} to="add" exact>Add Products</NavLink>
            <NavLink className={classes.right} to="cart"><StyledBadge badgeContent={count || ''} color="secondary"><ShoppingCartIcon></ShoppingCartIcon></StyledBadge></NavLink>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>;

};

export default NavBar;
```

We keep a state variable of the calculated value (or an error). `React.useEffect(func, [])` will call `func` once when the component gets mounted, which is when we start querying the data. If we get a count or error, store it in the state variable _(which will trigger React to re-render the component).

I've chosen to display an empty string in the badge while it's loading and ignore any error that happens. You might want to improve/change this of course.